# MacBook No Keyboard Input after xserver-xorg-input-synaptics install

Tags: keyboard, xorg, mouse, macbook, synaptics

I, maybe stupidly, installed xserver-xorg-input-synaptics to try to turn tap-to-click off.

Well, it worked, but **now I have no keyboard input at all.**

I can't use the terminal. Luckily I have no password for to login so I can get that far and use the character viewer to input text, but I can't hit enter so that is a problem. I am new to Linux and pretty new to the command line in general. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I am running Lubuntu 16.04 LTS on a MacBook 3,1

Update: I just restarted and now I have no trackpad input as well. I was messing with the settings so that could have done it